# How does one obtain an official Nintendo development SDK?

Tags: nintendo

I've seen before a topic here asking if there is any significant differences between using PALib or Nintendo's Nitro SDK... and that got me curious: what does it take to obtain the official SDK ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Costs I can't speak on personally, and I don't know if anyone who is a licensed developer can either. But there are some requirements that I do know of. I don't imagine it is that expensive because from what I saw around the internet the development kit for the Wii is under 5k.

What will cost you however, is having a brick-and-motar location dedicated to your studio's work. Nintendo requires this of it's licensees.

Following that, they also request back financials so that they can ensure that you would actually have the resources to bring your game to market.

If you think you qualify, you can [fill out the application to become a licensed Nintendo Developer](http://www.warioworld.com/apply/).

Comment: I believe that the 5k development kit for the Wii was only for the downloadable indie game store type of thing, and a "full development kit" would cost an order of magnitude more.  This is a common thing for all indie SDKs, though.

Comment: It feels like a pain that, apart from Xbox XNA, others don't have a indie friendly agreement.

Comment: @iamcreasy Yeah, I find the 3DS a handheld with a lot of potential but, as a hobbyist, I can't do much but wait for some 3rd party SDK and Flashcards to do my own experiments (Which I don't even know if they consider legal or not). They could at least offer a simpler license so you could sell stuff at the eShop. I would love it.

Comment: @thedaian You are right, Nintendo lists development licenses as being 2000 - 10000 depending on the size of your team. From what I can glean from the application it seems like you pay to become a registered developer and then you pay to get the development devices you require (at Nintendo's discretion)

Comment: Is it hard to get to that list? Do You have to fullfil some requirements? Do they check quality somehow if You are on this list?

Comment: Yes, they will investigate to make sure you are a legitimate company and all that, and they will likely want to talk to you and possibly have face-to-face meetings. Generally, alas, if you have to ask this kind of question you aren't in a position to become an officially licensed developer.

Answer (score 2):

$2,000 to $10,000 is the range given by Nintendo.

From [Nintendo of America](http://warioworld.com/apply/):

> Development Kits: Approximate development costs range from $2,000 to $10,000, depending on the size of your team. Financial stability is expected by Authorized Developers in order to purchase the necessary development equipment for your project.

Comment: Do you have a source for these numbers?

Comment: "Development Kits: Approximate development costs range from $2,000 to $10,000, depending on the size of your team. Financial stability is expected by Authorized Developers in order to purchase the necessary development equipment for your project." (Nintendo of America [http://www.warioworld.com/apply/])

Answer (score 1):

I'd say in most cases it's handled by the publisher.  Don't have a publisher/want to self publish?  Nintendo probably doesn't want to talk to you, then.  If you had some industry connections it might be a different story, of course.

It's a case of "if you have to ask, you'll never know".

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years ago I developed on the DS, the DS-Lite kit costed 1800$ which was way cheaper than any other dev-kit at the moment.

The Wii was a bit more expensive (I don't remember, 2500? 3500?) but you need to have at least two types, one for development (the black box) and one for creating the masters (green I think but I'm not sure).

For what it is worth:
Unofficially "everyone knew" that you had to request twice for being granted to be an authorised Nintendo developer...

Answer (score -3):

because of our NDA we can not talk about this much
but it might be a good idea to apply for a license yourself
it takes a few months to get a license (it took me 4 months), but then you can any question you want to the people of nintendo, but use the email that is registered with nintendo for that
what i can say is that nintendo uses HTML 5 and javascript development for its native SDK but has support for unity to
but for any further info please contact nintendo of america

Comment: also, dont forget that you will need windows for this, mac or linux isn't supported for compiling your nintendo programs

Comment: "HTML 5 and javascript development" for a native SDK? I don't think you know what the term native means.

Comment: an app for nintendo wiiU ware is written in HTML 5, javascript and css

Comment: and yes, in case you wonder, it is compiled and delivered as a native app, HTML used to be a scripting language for browsers only but in the time of modern HTML 5 it supports WebGL, Frame and other gaming features like support for Physics engines, the game is compiled as a browser with loads the HTML 5, Javascript and CSS from its bundle, so please, before you vote and answer down, do some research